# Exporting sql data from mysql server into csv file in local mac computer Help,

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, csv, terminal

when I attempt to take the data I have from my mysql server and generate a csv file with this command:

```
select * from table into outfile '/Users/username/Desktop/testfile.csv' fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '/n';
```

I end up with the error:

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/Users/username/Desktop/testfile.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Another weird problem is I can't seem to stop the server from running through the preference pane, maybe they are related. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Then in you terminal, cd to the tmp directory, do ls to see if the file is there and when you are in that tmp directory, just do open myfile.csv